# Page transition using react-router and react-addons-css-transition-group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, transition, react-router

I recently started learning React.js and I am now trying to play around with animations/transitions. I am using **React Router** and trying to implement very simple transition between pages with **ReactCSSTransitionGroup**. It works when I load/refresh the page but not when I go from page to page trough navigation links. Tried to make pages fade in with next code but it doesn't work:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base . --history-api-fallback"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <script src="/index.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router'
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
               <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
               <Link to="/about">About</Link>
               <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            </ul>
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500}>
                     {this.props.children}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default App;

class Home extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Home...</h1>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Home;

class About extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>About...</h1>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default About;

class Contact extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Contact...</h1>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Contact;

ReactDOM.render((
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path = "/" component = {App}>
         <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "home" component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "about" component = {About} />
         <Route path = "contact" component = {Contact} />
      </Route>
   </Router>

), document.getElementById('app'))
```

**app.css**

```
.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your `transitionEnterTimeout`/`transitionLeaveTimeout`? You've set `transitionAppearTimeout` but not the css for it, whereas you have set `enter`/`leave` css, but you did not set timeouts for it.

Comment: Wow.. i missed that. Thanks for pointing out, will edit my question. Fading still don't work on going from page to page trough navigation, only on load/refresh

Comment: Have you put the `enter` and `leave` timeout/css? You've only set for `appear`, thus it only happens when the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` loads; refresh.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/animations/app.js

Instead of just rendering this.props.children, you have to clone the component, pass it the children as props. React-router then uses the key for navigation.

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
    transitionName="example"
    transitionAppear={true}
    transitionAppearTimeout={500}
>
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { key: this.props.location.pathname })}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

Comment: Now weird thing happens. http://screencast.com/t/ffjBz31Q I went from home to about and then contact... and it is listing all headings down..